# Trying to Link_to_Asset (Laravel) cannot find the file (but it is there)

Tags: php, laravel

I have uploaded my files to the inner folder called App. Like this:

```
$destinationPath = app_path().'/uploads/' . $company;
$name = Input::file('fichero')->getClientOriginalName();
$file->move($destinationPath, $name);
```

That is, the tree is so:

```
- APP
- - UPLOADS
- - - COMPANY 1
- - - - file1.txt
- - - - file2.txt 
- - - -  more files
```

But when I try to link to them (to download them) like this:

```
<td>{{ link_to_asset('/uploads/' . $user->company. '/' . $user->filename, $user->filename) }}</td>
```

The error I get is
The requested URL /ocean was not found on this server. + 404

The files would have to be accessible only for those logged in, (that is why they are not in the Public folder), and I am logged in.

Any hint how?

thanks a lot

Comment: If it's not in your public directory, then it's not accessible to anyone unless you create some sort of controller that will read the requested file and then output it to the authorized users. In that case, the request should be made to the controller instead of the file.

Comment: Thank you very much! that helps a lot. I was sort of rubbing my chin that something like that had to be. I am going to give you the correct answer por caring to answer and pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Kemal pointed me in the right direction and here is how I solved it.
Instead of `link_to_asset` I had to use another function, which was:

```
<td>{{ HTML::linkAction('PostDocsController@downloaddocs', $user->filename , array($user->filename)) }}</td>
```

So, I created for this purpose the additional method `downloaddocs`.

In there I had to use another function which is specific for downloading:

```
return Response::download($pathToFile);
```